# does cout << fork() acctully call fork()?

Tags: c++, linux, fork, pid

I have a problem with fork function. Is

```
cout << fork();
```

acctully call fork() ?
I am trying to make process tree but still don't know how to manage the fork() function.
I wrote simple code to figure it, but it explain nothing.

```
int mainPID = getpid();
cout << "Main process: " << mainPID << endl << endl;

cout << fork() << endl;
cout << getpid() << endl;
cout << getppid() << endl;
```

It returns:
118,
119,
120
programme ends and get another values on screen 0, 118, 1
Is cout << fork() acctualy do fork() ?
I thought I get only values related to my mainPID.

Comment: By the time `fork()` finishes, there are two copies of your program, so *of course* it runs twice. The one that sees a return value of `0` is the newly-created child, the one that sees a PID number (of the child) is the parent.

Comment: Looks like C++ to me, not bash. Please tag your questions correctly.

Comment: This is a bad idea for two reasons: it doesn’t produce useful information, and it tells two different processes to write to the same resource simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

`fork()` returns twice: once in the original parent process, and also in the child process. In the parent process it returns the PID of the child. In the child process it returns `0`.

In both processes, the return value is then printed by `cout <<`. So you get multiple outputs.

If the parent process finishes quickly, it will exit before the child process calls `getppid()`. The child process will then be inherited by the `init` process, which is PID `1`. So the child prints `1` when it gets to `cout << getppid() << endl;`.

Comment: The child process runs first on current Linux kernels. This is because the child of a `fork()` usually calls `exec()` quickly, discarding its memory map and freeing the parent from the need to make every page of its memory copy-on-write.

Comment: @Davislor It takes enough time to do formatted output that it could perform a process switch back to the parent before any output is seen. Also, if there are multiple cores, they could both run at the same time on different CPUs.

Comment: Yes. On some systems you might get a 0 in the middle of the digits of the PID.

Comment: @Davislor Maybe possible, but very unlikely. `stdio` output to the terminal is line-buffered, so it won't write the digits in separate calls.

Comment: @Bamar Depends on a bunch of implementation details!

Answer (score 0):

`0` return value from child process with `cout << fork() << endl;`

`118` from child pid `cout << getpid() << endl;`

`1` from parent id `cout << getppid() << endl;` because real parent already exit so your child process was abandoned so It accepts `init` with pid = 1 as the new parent.

I recommend change some code to split child and parent process clearly, some thing like this

```
if ((pid = fork()) == -1) return -1;

if (pid == 0) 
    {
    //source for child process
    }else{
    //source for parent process
    }
```